# Absolute path in sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

There are two different controllers which have to invoke the Y action inside controller X. But the route varies according to the controller it is called from.

When Y called from controller A its route becomes A/X/Y
When Y called from controller B its route becomes B/X/Y
How can we make the route always be X/Y irrespective of the calling controller?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is ill posed.

You can extract the functionality from the action Y of Controller X to a [policy](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/policies)
and call it from all controllers that require it.

If you're familiar with express, every policy is an express middleware.